# calculate ROC using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, roc

I am trying to calculate receiver operating curve (ROC) using MS SQL Server. Following is the code.

```
DROP TABLE #Areas
SELECT CASE WHEN b.sensitivity> a.sensitivity THEN b.sensitivity ELSE
a.sensitivity END * abs(b.specificity-a.specificity)
+ Abs(b.sensitivity - a.sensitivity) * abs(b.specificity.specificity)/2
AS area
INTO #Areas
FROM #SensSpec a inner join #SensSpec b ON b.rnum-1 = a.rnum
```

I keep getting following error:

> Msg 258, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Cannot call methods on float

it's referring to "b.specificity" in this part of the code "abs(b.specificity.specificity)/2". how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `b.specificity.specificity` is supposed to be.  This should fix your problem:

```
SELECT ((CASE WHEN b.sensitivity> a.sensitivity THEN b.sensitivity
              ELSE a.sensitivity
         END) * abs(b.specificity - a.specificity) +
        (abs(b.sensitivity - a.sensitivity) * 
         abs(b.specificity - a.specificity) / 2
        )
       ) AS area
INTO #Areas
FROM #SensSpec a inner join
     #SensSpec b
     ON b.rnum - 1 = a.rnum;
```

This is not how I have calculated ROC values on data.  This calculation is using an inner join, so at the very least you are missing the end points of the range.

I prefer a calculation that uses cumulative window functions.  But the explanation is a bit long for a Stack Overflow answer.  I rare do this, but I do cover this top in **Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel, Second Edition**.